# как правильно кешировать в Redis отсортированные страницы c пагинацией? Laravel

Tags: laravel, redis

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/pokraska` вот так закешируется с пагинацией если переходить по страницам

```
$painters = Redis::remember('painters.' . $request->page ?? 1, $minutes, function () {
  return Painter::all();
});
```

а если выбрать фильтр то url будет типа `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pokraska?area=2121&city=116&price=asc&rating=asc` или некоторые пустые будут параметры к примеру `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pokraska?area=&city=&price=&rating=`

Как правильно кешировать чтобы кешировало только те параметры, которые уже открывались а если какое то изменить параметр к примеру город то должна же открыться страница не из кеша а из БД, так как страница с таким городом не была закеширована и как закешировать еще и её тогда?

Comment: Я же вам уже писал пример с простой пагинацией... Просто добавляйте свои ключи в ключ кеша `'painters.page' . $request->page ?? 1 . '.area' . $request->area` и так далее, модифицируйте ключ кеша

Comment: да я так уже сделал как раз спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Первый запрос - кеш пустой.
Формируешь ключ на основании параметров запроса `$cacheKey = md5(request()->toArray())`, сохраняешь результат из базы в кеш.

Второй зарос - параметры изменились? Да, ключ будет новый, в кеше пусто, запрос пойдет в базу. Нет, результат возьмется из кеша.

Comment: А если потом вдруг надо будет посмотреть что в кеше? И вдруг клиент случайно добавит какой то ключ в гет?

Comment: Если нужно почистить, то нужно использовать тегированный кеш на эту тему лучше посмотреть на оф. сайте https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#cache-tags

Comment: Я о другом а именно о том что бы получить содержимое кеша в другом месте, да и насколько помню md5 только строки принимает

Comment: Если нужно получить тот же результат, то и входные параметры должны быть одинаковы, чтобы md5 от них вернул тот же результат. Обычно кэш сбрасывают.

Comment: А вы уверены что request()->toArray всегд будет давать одинаковый рещультат? И повторюсь md5 работает со строками

Comment: При одинаковых параметрах запроса будет всегда одинаковый результат. Касаемо md5, можно воспользоваться `$key = md5(json_encode($request->toArray))`.